# OkHttp ignore logging interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I faced with strange problem.
OkHttp gives me log like this:

> I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
>
> I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<

But I declarated logging interceptor in Client initialization.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);

OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request original = chain.request();
            Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(config.login(), config.password()));
            Request request = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        })
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);

return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(config.getServer())
        .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        .addConverterFactory(getMoshiConverterFactory())
        .client(client.build())
        .build();
```

And my **gradle** contains:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.7.0'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some I time I figurate what logs this Sony device show and make a copy of `okhttp-logging-interceptor` where I replace

```
Platform.get().log(INFO, message, null);
```

with

```
Log.i("Retrofit", message)
```

because device show's only `System.out`, `Log.i`, `Log.w` and `Log.e` logs from app.

Answer (score 3):

You could use it as a network intercepter instead an application interceptor. Do `.addNetworkInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);` instead of `.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);`

This lets you "Observe the data just as it will be transmitted over the network".

See more information [in the wiki pages.](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors)

Comment: Interesting answer, but did not help. I dont know, may be it is because of device, But have no other. As true Android developer I have only iPhone and emulation does not support by my temporary PC(

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            Log.d("OkHttp", message);
        }
    });
```

Try this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this post on Github that help me solve the problem.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3985#issuecomment-465505085

In resume, some devices by default (even with developer options on) do not log verbose and debug messages.

Checking the build properties of the device gives the following result:

> adb shell getprop log.tag
>
> I

After changing I to V (or just VERBOSE) using adb shell setprop log.tag VERBOSE:

Note: This setting might not persist when rebooting the phone!

So this is not an OkHttp issue, but a system setting on some devices.